i want to authinticate users to a specific page using laravel
i want to make a authentication system when a user login they should be taken to a specific page, like a profile or dashboard?
how should i do it using laravel framework 11.
i haven't tried anything yet because i am fairly new to this framework.
i have a login page set in the framework but i was wondering to authenticate users to a dashboard or a page.
what are the best options i can go with, if there is any tutorials that would help me make this happen would be appreciated.
thank you in advance.

yeah like a cms that could store all the data and authenticate whoever registers and try to login.

Please check the ans there is official authentication mention how to do that.

You can Used Laravel Authentication For authenticate users even there are Define the guards option also available.
you have to check official Laravel Documentation For Define Guards : https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/authentication

i have seen it i want my own custom  authentication, the documentation refers to install breeze which i dont want to use it, i want my own

@AzizKhan https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/multi-user-authentication-system-in-laravel-11

@AzizKhan there is also custom guard option you have..  as well above link check for references

@AzizKhan okay You still face any issue , drop msg here !!
